# Plot of Ic and Vbe function

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, bjt, circuit-design

The [book](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=ap5ZdUAEcQ0C&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=current%20conveyor%20tutorial&source=bl&ots=e3_4FvJZwb&sig=08ou1e4_BV0mOp22IJ7-vt0Y560&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=current%20conveyor%20tutorial&f=false) page 12 show the plot of collector current Ic vs temperature at fixed Vbe =600mV.

With the equation: Ic = Is*e^(Vbe/VT).

Where Is = 10^-16A.

Vbe = 0.6V
      VT = kT/q = -8.6173324×10−5*T (V/K)

I tried to plot the function for temperature from -55 to 125C (or 218 to 398K).

However, the result is totally different from the plot in the book. Could you explain?

I understand that Is also varies with temp but I think Is is fixed in the plot.

Thank you.

Book plot:
[image]

My plot:

[image: t]

Comment: Did you notice that the scales in the book are different, and that the scale of the current in the book is logarithmic?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem. If you notice the current Ic at the same temp of two figures are totally different.

Comment: It is difficult to compare since the axis are completely different. Try to make your graph with exactly rhe same axis as the book graph

Comment: As you can see from the book plot, the minimum value of Ic is 100pA. However, from my plot, it is much smaller than 2x10^-25A. That is totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a mistake in your calculations....

At 300 kelvin kT/q = 26 mV so \$e^{\frac{0.6V}{0.026V}}\$ = 1.05E10

Multiply this by 1E-16 and I get a current of 1.05 uA or very nearly the same as the proper graph.

Comment: Thank you. I am checking it again but from the equation, Ic should decrease as temp increases. However, the book graph doesn't agree with this. I am not thinking that in their plot, Is is not constant at all. It increases rapidly with temperature.

Comment: In my plot, I also made a mistake when using negative value for electron charge.